# Yii2 связь один ко многим с Null-object

Tags: php, yii2, шаблоны-проектирования, activerecord

Собственно сабж, есть 2 сущности связанные отношением один ко многим. Множество - набор сущностей, из некоторого временного интервала, каждая из них ограничена своим временным интервалом:

Entity 1

```
id, field1,...
1,  value1,...
```

Entity 2

```
entity1_id, from,                till,                field1,...
1,          2017-01-10 10:00:00, 2017-01-11 10:00:00, value1,...
1,          2017-01-11 10:35:00, 2017-01-12 10:35:00, value2,...
```

Entity 1 связанна с Entity 2 отношением один ко многим.

Сущности типа Entity 2 создаются пользователями.

В виду того что сущности не заполняют временную линию непрерывно, есть проверки на null во множестве мест.

Хочется избавится от проверок на null введением "Null объекта" в каком месте жизненного цикла active record/active query это лучше реализовывать.

Нужны советы в какую сторону копать...

Answer (score 1):

Прежде, чем воспользоваться ответом ниже, советую все-таки пересмотреть свое отношение к данному вопросу. Данные обязательно нужно всегда проверять, если Вам не очень нравится постоянно проверять объект на NULL в данном контексте, то представьте, что Вам может не понравится потом? Я бы посоветовал все-таки откинуть на второй план собственные "нехотелки", в программировании очень много чего делать не хочется, но приходится.

**Теперь собственно к самому ответу:**

Методы `hasOne` и `hasMany` возвращают объект `ActiveQuery`, который в свою очередь наследуется от объекта `Query`, который наследуется от `Component`. `Component` в свою очередь имеет магические геттер и сеттер.

Соответственно, в моделях, если Вы хотите вернуть болванку в случае NULL, Вам просто нужно вернуть новый пустой объект `ActiveQuery`. Однако, если заглянуть в класс `Component`, мы увидим, что в методе `__get` выбрасываются исключения, если происходит попытка обращения к несуществующему методу или свойству. Если я не ошибаюсь, то в режиме продакшена, эти исключения никак не повлияют на работоспособность сайта, но они неизбежно будут приводить к остановке работоспособности в режиме разработки, поэтому есть 2 варианта:

1. в методах `hasOne` и `hasMany` моделей делаем проверку - вернули ли нам NULL или все-таки Объект. Если вернули NULL - то просто возвращаем пустой новый объект `ActiveQuery` (в таком случае в продакшене исключения будут ловиться и конечный пользователь не увидит ошибку, а лишь пустые значения)
2. Повторяем то же самое, что и в первом пункте, но вместо объекта ActiveQuery возвращаем свой созданный новый класс `NullObject` (только не пихайте его в базовые папки Yii), в котором мы пишем метод `__get` так, чтобы он возвращал NULL

Иными словами для 1ого варианта:

```
public function getQuery() {
        $activeQuery = $this->hasOne( Queries::class , [ 'id' => 'query_id' ] );

        return $activeQuery ? $activeQuery : new ActiveQuery();
    }
```

Или для 2ого варианта с использованием PHP 7+:

```
public function getQuery() {
        $activeQuery = $this->hasOne( Queries::class , [ 'id' => 'query_id' ] );

        return $activeQuery ? $activeQuery : new class( ){public function __get($name) { return NULL;}};
    }
```

А тем временем, я только сейчас заметил, что этому вопросу полтора года.

Answer (score -1):

в моделе есть связь, допустим:

```
public function getProfile(){
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::className(),['user_id'=>'id']);}
```

Она может возвращать null и вы хотите не проверять во view а сделать проверку в моделе? Если да, то кто мещает сделать так:

```
public function getMyProfile(){
      $data = 'пусто'; // или пустой массив если hasMany
    if($this->profile)
      $data = $this->profile; 
    return $data;}
```

и использовать myProfile вместо profile

Comment: Нет мне надо не во вьюхе null как то проверить, а именно по hasMany получить не только ActiveRecord с соответствующими записями но и объекты заглушки которые будут содержать некоторые данные и это не всегда будет, пусто. Хотя да ваш вариант дергать из другого метода неплох...

Comment: Тогда давайте Ваш код. Пока совсем не понятно что вы там придумали. Очень все странно

Answer (score -2):

#### Откройте модель класс которую открыли в таблицу 'Entity 2'. Там должно быть функция

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['entity1_id', 'till', 'field1' ...], 'required'],
            ...
        ];
    }
```

#### Если вам не надо проверок на null удалите строку где написано 'required'

#### Нo если вам не надо проверить на null только 'field1', то удалите только самого 'field1'

Comment: Да видимо я не умею правильно объяснять... Суть в том что это нужно не просто для вывода, а для работы последующей логики... Т.е. Я либо буду получать ошибки, либо буду проверять на null по этому мне видимо нужно в момент инстанцирования связанных объектов находить пробелы и генерировать null-object но как это сделать?